# Page event or goal definition not found

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

With a Sitecore XC 9.2.0 instance (created from scratch) I got the following errors about page event definition not being found:

```
45868 21:31:35 ERROR Page event or goal definition Visited Product Details Page not found, page URL /shop/4K=habitat_master-4k/HabitatSpectra48”4KLEDUltraHDTelevision=6042262
45156 21:31:42 ERROR Page event or goal definition Lines Added To Cart not found, page URL /api/cxa/Cart/AddCartLine?sc_site=Storefront
45916 21:32:41 ERROR Page event or goal definition Lines Updated On Cart not found, page URL /api/cxa/cart/UpdateCartLineQuantity?sc_site=Storefront
47128 21:32:45 ERROR Page event or goal definition Lines Removed From Cart not found, page URL /api/cxa/cart/RemoveShoppingCartLine?sc_site=Storefront
```

Does anyone have these errors as well and know how to solve this? 
I've already deployed the marketing definitions. 
I can see the page event in the content editor under the folder */sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/CommerceConnect/Cart*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got these errors because I didn't do the "Common.RebuildDescendants" task during installation which rebuild the Descendants table in the database.

After doing the task (part of doing the cleanup database task in the control panel) the error was gone.